# Button to the left side of navbar-brand

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to put a button on the left side of navbar-brand for toggling a sidebar. The button toggles the sidebar. In desktop mode, it works fine but on smaller screens, it changes position and comes to the right side of the navbar-brand.
Here are the screenshots.

[image]

[image]

```
    <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar">
                    <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>
                <button type="button" data-toggle="#sidebar" id="sidebar-toggle" class="navbar-left navbar-toggle">
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>
                <a class="navbar-brand" href="Login.aspx" style="vertical-align: middle">
                    <img src="Logo.png" style="vertical-align: middle" /></a>
                <label class="navbar-text text-center text-primary" style="vertical-align:10px;font-size:medium">Example Distribution</label>
            </div>
            <div class="navbar-collapse collapse" id="navbar">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                    <li><a href="#">Dashboard</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Settings</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Profile</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Help</a></li>
                </ul>
                <form class="navbar-form navbar-right">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search..." />
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </nav>
    <div class="container-sidebar">
        <div id="sidebar">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Explore</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Users</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Sign Out</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Post related css also.

Comment: On media query for mobile device add the css of that button there.

Comment: Its the same as navbar-toggle button with a css #sidebar-toggle {
            display: block;
            left: 5px;
        }

Comment: could you provide a fiddle?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/7754/

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/7755/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add this code on `document.ready`

There might be CSS alternative but I feel this is easy!

**[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/Guruprasad_Rao/DTcHh/7756/)**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    if($(window).width()<768)
    {
        $('#sidebar-toggle').css('float','left');
    }
    $(window).on('resize',function(){
        if($(window).width()<768)
        {
            console.log('here');
              $('#sidebar-toggle').css('float','left');
        }
    });
});
```

CSS Solution:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
     #sidebar-toggle{
        float:left !important;
     }
}
```

Updated **[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/Guruprasad_Rao/DTcHh/7757/)**

Comment: Why javascript? Two lines of css sorts the problem :)

Comment: @Morpheus.  Ok now?? :)

Answer (score 5):

Just add this css class `pull-left`  **[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/sheshu036/7auezk9z/)**

```
  <button type="button" data-toggle="#sidebar" id="sidebar-toggle" class=" navbar-toggle pull-left">
```